# onBackPressed() finishes my Activity

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

In my project I have just one `Activity` that have `View`.
I think that it has two `View` that switch the `View`. The first `View` is my home that has one `Button` named "play" . when You click play `Button` in goes to the second `View`. Second `View` is my game.
And now my problem is that when I want to use `onBackPressed()` method in the second `View`, it closes the `Activity`. and  `onBackPressed()` method do the same in both `View`.
How to handle `onBackPressed()` method in second `View` that return to the first `View`.
How to switch the `View` in `onBackPressed()`?
I am new with Android and now I really confused.
any suggestion? or any key word to search to solve my problem.

here is my code:

```
 public class PTPlayer extends Cocos2dxActivity {

static Splash splash;
public static AppList appList;
static Noti_Queue noti_queue;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    Log.v("----------", "onActivityResult: request: " + requestCode + " result: " + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == PTServicesBridge.RC_SIGN_IN) {
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    if (splash == null) {
        splash = new Splash(this);
        splash.set_identity("1");
    }


    if (appList == null) {
        appList = new AppList(this);
        appList.set_identity("1");
    }


    if (noti_queue == null) {
        noti_queue = new Noti_Queue(this);
        noti_queue.set_identity("1");
    }


}

@Override
public void onNativeInit() {
    initBridges();
}

private void initBridges() {
    PTStoreBridge.initBridge(this);
    PTServicesBridge.initBridge(this, getString(R.string.app_id));

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
        PTAdChartboostBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kRevMob")) {
        PTAdRevMobBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kAdMob") || PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kFacebook")) {
        PTAdAdMobBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kAppLovin")) {
        PTAdAppLovinBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kLeadBolt")) {
        PTAdLeadBoltBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kVungle")) {
        PTAdVungleBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kPlayhaven")) {
        PTAdUpsightBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kMoPub")) {
        PTAdMoPubBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kFacebook")) {
        PTAdFacebookBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kHeyzap")) {
        PTAdHeyzapBridge.initBridge(this);
    }

}

@Override
public Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView onCreateView() {
    Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = new Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0);

    return glSurfaceView;
}

static {
    System.loadLibrary("player");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
        PTAdChartboostBridge.onResume(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
        PTAdChartboostBridge.onStart(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
        PTAdChartboostBridge.onStop(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    splash.Display();
    splash = null;
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

here i think that in my second view:

```
     public abstract class Cocos2dxActivity extends Activity implements  Cocos2dxHelperListener {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final String TAG = Cocos2dxActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
private Cocos2dxHandler mHandler;
private static Context sContext = null;

public static Context getContext() {
    return sContext;
}

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sContext = this;
    this.mHandler = new Cocos2dxHandler(this);

    this.init();

    Cocos2dxHelper.init(this, this);


}

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Cocos2dxHelper.onResume();
    this.mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Cocos2dxHelper.onPause();
    this.mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void showDialog(final String pTitle, final String pMessage) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = Cocos2dxHandler.HANDLER_SHOW_DIALOG;
    msg.obj = new Cocos2dxHandler.DialogMessage(pTitle, pMessage);
    this.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

@Override
public void showEditTextDialog(final String pTitle, final String pContent, final int pInputMode, final int pInputFlag, final int pReturnType, final int pMaxLength) { 
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = Cocos2dxHandler.HANDLER_SHOW_EDITBOX_DIALOG;
    msg.obj = new Cocos2dxHandler.EditBoxMessage(pTitle, pContent, pInputMode, pInputFlag, pReturnType, pMaxLength);
    this.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

@Override
public void runOnGLThread(final Runnable pRunnable) {
    this.mGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(pRunnable);
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================
public void init() {

    // FrameLayout
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams framelayout_params =
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    framelayout.setLayoutParams(framelayout_params);

    // Cocos2dxEditText layout
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams edittext_layout_params =
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);




    this.mGLSurfaceView = this.onCreateView();



    // Switch to supported OpenGL (ARGB888) mode on emulator
    if (isAndroidEmulator())
       this.mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

    this.mGLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());


            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new           RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    //AdView adad = new AdView(this);
    ClickBanner_CLickYab_Holder adad = new ClickBanner_CLickYab_Holder(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adad_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adad_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    adad_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    // adad.setToken(getString(R.string.adad_token));
    adad.setLayoutParams(adad_params);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);


    myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adad_params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adad_params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    adad_params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(adad_params1);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PTPlayer.appList.Display();
        }
    });

    Button myButton1 = new Button(this);


    myButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adad_params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adad_params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    adad_params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    myButton1.setLayoutParams(adad_params2);
    myButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PTPlayer.appList.Display();
        }
    });


    relativeLayout.addView(this.mGLSurfaceView);
    relativeLayout.addView(adad);
    relativeLayout.addView(myButton);
    relativeLayout.addView(myButton1);
    ClickBanner_CLickYab_Holder.setTestMode();
    setContentView(relativeLayout);




}

public Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView onCreateView() {
    return new Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView(this);
}

     private final static boolean isAndroidEmulator() {
  String model = Build.MODEL;
  Log.d(TAG, "model=" + model);
  String product = Build.PRODUCT;
  Log.d(TAG, "product=" + product);
  boolean isEmulator = false;
  if (product != null) {
     isEmulator = product.equals("sdk") || product.contains("_sdk") ||     product.contains("sdk_");
  }
  Log.d(TAG, "isEmulator=" + isEmulator);
  return isEmulator;
}
}
```

Comment: what do you wanna do actually ?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I want when I used onbackpresed the second view goes to first view

Answer (score 4):

you must use of Override Method for when back button pressed
if you want to stay on currnt activity use like this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }
```

if you want to use double click to exit and one click to stay you can use like this

first define a variable for double click

```
boolean doubleBackToExit = false;
```

and the Override backbutton method

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExit) {
         //on double back button pressed
            return;
        }
        this.doubleBackToExit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExit=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding onBackPressed() of the activity and provide your screen where you want to go.
onBackpressed() check which is the current view you are showing and according to move to the first view.

Comment: how?would you please explain more

Comment: @nsr set a flag which will indicate what you are showing on you activity.If it is firstview set it as firstview and vice versa for second view.onBackpressed() check which view is showing according to that show the view.Hope now this will help me.And vote the answer if you found useful.

Comment: I have 2 activity but when i use onbackpress it close both activity

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526533/moving-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android](link) .See the launch mode of activity in the manifest file.

Comment: this is about activity my question is something else

Answer (score 1):

Just don't call the `super.onBackPressed()` everytime.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       if (isFirstView()) {
          super.onBackPressed();
      } else {
          switchToFirstView();
      }
```

Call in only when there isn't any last view available. Or where you want to close the App. The code will finish your activity when you are on the first activity. And switch to first activity if you are on second activity.
Just replace my methods as per your code.

Comment: what is islastview() and swtichtopreviuosview()?

Comment: Just gave you the logic to switch the views. You atleast switch the views by yourself. Thank you.

Comment: my problem is that exactly how to switch to the next view

Answer (score 1):

Then do this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityPhase2.this, GlobalSearch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your second class  Cocos2dxActivity, place this code.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one activity with two `View` you can use `Fragments`.
Using Fragments, Activity.OnBackPressed() will remove last fragment in the stack and you can resolve your problem.

So, in the activity you have to put a *container* in xml layout file:

`<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

In the Activity java file:

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .add(R.id.container,new YourHomeFragment())
          .commit();`

So to add second Fragment you can use this code:

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .add(R.id.container,new YourPlayFragment())
          .addToBackStack("YourPlayFragment") //string what you want
          .commit();`

Pay attention: you can call this code or in YourHomeFragment class (into button clickListener) or in your Activity (using a callback system). For example:

In YourHomeFragment -->
`playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                   .add(R.id.container,new YourPlayFragment())
                   .addToBackStack("YourPlayFragment") //string what you want
                   .commit();
            }
        });`

In this way, you have to declare two layout xml file for fragments and one for Activity.

List of java and relative xml files:

`MainActivity.java`
`activity_main.xml`

`YourHomeFragment.java`
`fragment_your_home.xml` <-- insert here your first View

`YourPlayFragment.java`
`fragment_your_play.xml` <-- play view

Comment: my activity dont have any layout

Comment: mh ok. You can try to use FrameLayout declared in init() method. `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .add(framelayout.getId(),new YourHomeFragment())
          .commit();`