# How to go from one actvity to ther in android studio using button

Tags: android

I Have created 2 activities. The first one is named activity_main.xml and the other one layout.xml
I have a button in the first one and I want thst on clicking it I reach layout.xml
How do I do this?
 
This is the code for the button:

I am a beginner so it will be better if anyone can give me step by step instructions

Comment: just follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526533/moving-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: I don't use a virtual device

Comment: Try the code Siddiqui,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button id from the `activity_main.xml` will be used to call the event for going from `ActivityMain` to `SecondActivity`, don't forget to initialise the button in onCraete.

Use this code(inside `onCreate` is preferred, not necessarily):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id_from_activity_main.xml);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   startActivity(new Intent(your_activity_name.this, second_activity_to_go.class););
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent to call the SecondActivity. If in your activity_main.xml there is an Button. Then provide onClickListnere on the Button to call the Second Activity.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           }
});
```

Comment: Do I enter in this in mainActivity.java

Comment: Yes, that MainActivity must be having activity_main.xml. And in this, you must have a Button, whose id must be button. Then use the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                     startActivity(i);            
}
            });
```