# How to pass activity to a function in kotlin

Tags: android, function, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

How to pass activity to a function in kotlin
I have buttons that pass one activity to another so I want to write intent in a function in order to do that I have to pass activity to which we need to go after pressing the button. So how can I pass activity to a function in kotlin?

I know how to move from one activity to another .I just want to know if I want Activity in parameter what to write here in kotlin: private fun replaceActivity(what to write here) –

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    replaceActivity(MenuActivity())
}
fun replaceActivity(activity: Activity) {
 val intent = Intent(this, activity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
}
```

replaceActivity(MenuActivity::class.java) this is how I am calling the function

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand the question correctly, do you have multiple activities in your app? or do you want to simple pass the activity reference to a fragment or a function ?

Comment: I have multiple activities and I made a function where intent is written to move one activity to another.

Comment: I just want to know how to pass activity name to that function

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526533/moving-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android) might help you

Comment: I know how to move from one activity to another .I just want to know if I want Activity in parameter what to write here  in kotlin:   private fun replaceActivity(what to write here)

Comment: replaceActivity(MenuActivity::class.java) this is how I am calling the function

Comment: well, depends whether this ONLY MenuActivity or other activities too

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing, but if I understood correctly:

If you want to be able to only pass MenuActivity to the function:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        replaceActivity(MenuActivity::class.java) // doesn't necessarily need to be here
    }
    fun replaceActivity(classOfMenuActivity: Class<MenuActivity>) {
      // do something with that class
    }
```

if you want to pass activities (that aren't the same, so not only AnotherActivity class):

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        replaceActivity(AnotherActivity())
    }
    fun replaceActivity(activity: Activity) {
      // do something with that activity
        val classOfTheActivity = activity::class.java
    }
```

Also, creating apps with multiple activities is... a mess, nowadays all of the apps are written with one activity and multiple fragments, if you are wondering why check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10515807/15749574) out

Comment: thats exactly what I was saying but I have following error "Classifier 'MenuActivity' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here"  on AnotherActivity() in replaceActivity(AnotherActivity())

Comment: that's strange, could you add the code you are mentioning to the question?

Comment: i have added my code in the question